# How to avoid duplicate rows when constructing a UITableViewCell from UILabel subviews

Tags: uitableview, ios5, duplicates, subviews

I'm loading an array of dictionary elements containing US state data into a UITableView and I'm experiencing duplicate rows when the user scrolls down to offscreen items - row 1 is duplicated at row 8, row 2 is duplicated at row 9, etc.

I've reviewed the following SO questions and implemented some of their suggestions (without success):

[2994472](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994472/my-uitableview-has-duplicated-rows) - My UITableView has duplicate rows

[7056578](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056578/uitableview-repeating-cells-when-scrolled) - UITableView repeating cells when scrolled

The UITableViewCell is a custom construction, created from UILabels. Here's the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
00    const int ABBREVIATION = 1, STATE = 2 // Declared outside cellForRowAtIndexPath


01    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
02    
03    UILabel *abbreviation, *state;
04    
05    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
06    if (cell == nil) {
07        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault         
08              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
09        
10        abbreviation = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7.0, 1.0, 34.0, 30.0 )];
11        abbreviation.tag = ABBREVIATION; 
12        abbreviation.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0];
13        abbreviation.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
14        abbreviation.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
15
16        state = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42.0, 1.0, 158.0, 30.0)];
17        state.tag = STATE;
18        state.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0];
19        state.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
20        state.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
21
22        [cell.contentView addSubview:abbreviation];
23        [cell.contentView addSubview:state];
24    
25        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
26        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
27    }
28    
29    abbreviation.text = [[self.primaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"abbreviation"];
30    state.text = [[self.stateInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
31    
32    return cell;
```

Follow the advice in 2994472, I modifying lines 27 and 28 to use a ternary operator.

```
29   abbreviation.text = [[self.primaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"abbreviation"] ?
                         [[self.primaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"abbreviation"] :
                         @"";

30   state.text = [[self.stateInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] ?
                  [[self.stateInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] : 
                  @"";
```

That didn't work, the duplication still occurs starting on row 8.

What appears to solve the problem is referencing the UILabel tag when setting the label text to drill down to the actual subview.

```
29  ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:ABBREVIATION]).text = [[self.primaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"abbreviation"];
30  ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:STATE]).text = [[self.primaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

When the cell subviews are referenced this way the UITableView row duplication disappears.

Comment: In your first version the error comes form the fact that you're keeping the last alloc'ed version of your variables abbreviation and state, your last version is correct because it links the variables to the cell. But you have the answer, was there a question ?

Comment: How would you suggest releasing the last allocated versions of abbreviation and state (I'm using iOS 5 with ARC enabled for this file)? Also, I posted this in case anyone else runs into a similar situation.

Comment: You should just release it after adding with addSubView, addSubView will retain it and by releasing you pass the memory mgt to the uitbaleview code. With your posted code memory usage will most likely keep growing.

Comment: "release" is not available in iOS' automatic reference counting mode. Do you suggest I disable ARC for this file or the entire project?

Comment: No I made this comment ignoring you enabled ARC, and I've not used it myself. But as I understand your code abbreviation and state must be declared as ivars so in scope of the instance life time, I would suggest to declare them locally, then ARC should get rid of them at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I was able to post a solution in my original question, I still was wondering why the duplicate cell situation was happening in the first place.

Did some additional research, writing out the text values for the state and abbreviation values alongside the values displayed in the cells.

```
(A) NSLog(@"%@", state.text);
(B) NSLog(@"%@", ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:STATE]).text);
```

The results displayed are interesting and throw some light on the situation.

```
 (A)               (B)
 Iowa              Iowa
 New Hampshire     New Hampshire
 South Carolina    South Carolina
 Florida           Florida
 Nevada            Nevada
 Colorado          Colorado
 Minnesota         Minnesota
 (null)            Iowa
 (null)            New Hampshire
 (null)            SouthCarolina
 (null)            Florida
```

The (null) values appear when scrolling up to display additional states.

So what I think is happening is when the scrolling down happens, the original code in lines 29 and 30 attempts to set the text values of the two instance variables.

```
29    abbreviation.text = [[self.primaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"abbreviation"];
30    state.text = [[self.stateInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

But since they've been automatically dereferenced by ARC, they don't exist anymore, cannot be set, and return a value of null. However the cells which contain the original values are "dequeued" and reused with the old data, causing duplicates to appear.

Let me know if I'm totally off base with this hypothesis.

Comment: You are 100% correct. It reuses the old cells **with** their old data. You need to re-initialize everything in the cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the case that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns an existing table view cell, so that your `if` block is skipped, your `abbreviation` and `state` variables are not set. So in this case (which would happen when you begin scrolling and thus displaying reused cells), `abbreviation` and `state` are nil at the end of your function so the reused cell's labels are not being updated as you expect. You probably want an `else` block where you set the abbreviation and state vars to point to the correct subviews of the `cell`.

Comment: But the lines of code that set the text values for abbreviation and state are outside the if (cell == nil) block. What you say is true - when an existing cell is reused the creation code is skipped but the value setting code will always be run.

Are you saying that because we're reusing a cell, the references to the UILabel subviews in the reused cell are nil and can't be accessed?

Comment: Perhaps when I read your question I missed the `viewWithTag` lines of code at the bottom of your question. Those two viewWithTag statements are what I was suggesting you put in the `else` block. Perhaps the `viewWithTag` calls are returning nil though, I'm going off memory here but you may need to use `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ABBREVIATION]`, etc., instead of `[cell viewWithTag:ABBREVIATION]`.

Comment: Both [cell viewWithTag:ABBREVIATION] and [cell.contentView viewWithTag:ABBREVIATION] work.